# saving settings and reinstalling them

Tags: customtkinter

how to make a window in customtkinter, add a settings button where, using CTkSwitch, you can configure the main window on top of other windows or not, and if you open the settings window again, all parameters will be saved and set
to give an example I have no idea :(

I tried to do this myself, but it turned out so that everything worked, but when I ran the settings again, let’s say this is a function that determines whether my window is on top of other windows, my window could work something like this:
slider is off
but the window is still on top of all windows

I only need help in ensuring that the previously set parameters are installed when restarting